# py2exe can't find .py

Tags: python, pygame, converters, py2exe

Sorry if this is a really stupid question,
**How do I get the py2exe to find the module I wish to convert?**
I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'dist_dir'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running py2exe
creating C:\Users\David\workspace\setup\src\dist
*** searching for required modules ***
error: Pygame.py: No such file or directory
```

I looked up as many Pygame to `.exe` tutorials or problems others have had, but their problem seemed to occur AFTER they created a `.exe` file...
I can't even get it to create one.
I used the exact same code as the one found on http://pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe except that I changed:

```
class BuildeExe:
 def __init__(self):
     #Name of starting .py
     self.script = "MyApps.py"
```

into

```
class BuildExe:
 def __init__(self):
     #Name of starting .py
     self.script = "Pygame.py"
```

My Pygame.py exists in "C:\Users\"username"\workspace\pygame\src". Please help.

Comment: This might help. http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe?parent=CookBook

Comment: hmmm... I believe is has the same code from the link I posted. I tried it but it didn't work. Thank you anyway ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can try putting this in a .py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

such as how they do in [this](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) tutorial.  Then all you have to do is oppen up cmd.exe and cd to your "C:\Users\"username"\workspace\pygame\src" and type:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

or you can changed the setup.py to whatever .py file you saved the above code in. (within the same directory as you gave)

Comment: I believe that is for converting a regular python program to exe. Because the code I'm trying to convert uses pygame I think it needs something a little more complex than the code you suggested. I tried this code before and gave me errors regarding the usage of pygame...